# Problems with android versions

Tags: android, version

I'm working on a app which should run on different android versions. I'm using SQLite and have set up my app as follows:

```
Android: 4.2.2
Platform: 4.2.2
API Level: 17
```

Manifest file

```
Android:minSdkVersion: "8"
Android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

On my Galaxy S3 everything works fine. But on a Galaxy 2 Plus the installation runs normally and the startup of the app crashes.

Can I simply change a parameter and rebuild it? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: This sounds like an attempt to use a feature from API 17 that is unavailable on Galaxy 2 Plus. Please change Android build target to 8, that way you will be immediately notified (with errors) of potentially problematic code. After you identified the issue, please use @TargetApi with conjunction of if clauses to validate API version prior to using code that is not present in API 8.

Comment: so, i've changed the TargetApi to 8 and it worked fine.
Thank you!